# Can't compile simple program with tcp.h because of error from endianess?

Tags: c, tcp, compiler-errors, sniffing, man-in-the-middle

Help me compile this simple C program using tcp.h? Getting "mitmc.c:82: error: struct tcphdr has no member named th_off" because the byte order is not set with "# ifdef __FAVOR_BSD"

This is prolly a simple problem for some of you. I'm trying to compile [this](http://pastebin.com/qCcC6hhR) program, a simple man in the middle utility from a book.  Compiling with gcc on linux (because Windows didnt have the posix library).

First I got this error:

```
mitmc.c: In function âcorrupt_ip_pktâ:
mitmc.c:82: error: âstruct tcphdrâ has no member named âth_offâ
mitmc.c:109: error: âstruct udphdrâ has no member named âuh_ulenâ
```

and it looks like this is because in "/usr/include/netinet/tcp.h" th_off is only defined if 
    # ifdef __FAVOR_BSD

But when I define it by adding
     #define _BSD_SOURCE
(because it is set in features.h http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/tcp-hdr-variables-388003/), then I get a whole other set of errors:

```
$ gcc mitmc.c
/tmp/ccuzRcNp.o: In function `corrupt_ip_pkt':
mitmc.c:(.text+0x15f): undefined reference to `libnet_do_checksum'
mitmc.c:(.text+0x174): undefined reference to `libnet_geterror'
mitmc.c:(.text+0x231): undefined reference to `libnet_do_checksum'
mitmc.c:(.text+0x242): undefined reference to `libnet_geterror'
mitmc.c:(.text+0x296): undefined reference to `libnet_do_checksum'
mitmc.c:(.text+0x2a7): undefined reference to `libnet_geterror'
/tmp/ccuzRcNp.o: In function `pkt_handler':
mitmc.c:(.text+0x346): undefined reference to `libnet_write_raw_ipv4'
mitmc.c:(.text+0x357): undefined reference to `libnet_geterror'
/tmp/ccuzRcNp.o: In function `main':
mitmc.c:(.text+0x466): undefined reference to `libnet_init'
mitmc.c:(.text+0x4ae): undefined reference to `libnet_get_hwaddr'
mitmc.c:(.text+0x4c6): undefined reference to `libnet_geterror'
mitmc.c:(.text+0x590): undefined reference to `strlcat'
mitmc.c:(.text+0x5c0): undefined reference to `strlcat'
mitmc.c:(.text+0x5df): undefined reference to `pcap_lookupdev'
mitmc.c:(.text+0x63c): undefined reference to `pcap_lookupnet'
mitmc.c:(.text+0x697): undefined reference to `pcap_open_live'
mitmc.c:(.text+0x6fc): undefined reference to `pcap_compile'
mitmc.c:(.text+0x715): undefined reference to `pcap_perror'
mitmc.c:(.text+0x736): undefined reference to `pcap_setfilter'
mitmc.c:(.text+0x74f): undefined reference to `pcap_perror'
mitmc.c:(.text+0x767): undefined reference to `pcap_freecode'
mitmc.c:(.text+0x7ad): undefined reference to `pcap_loop'
mitmc.c:(.text+0x7cd): undefined reference to `pcap_perror'
mitmc.c:(.text+0x7e6): undefined reference to `pcap_close'
mitmc.c:(.text+0x7f3): undefined reference to `libnet_destroy'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Thanks for any help.

Plus, BTW, why do my compiler errors sometimes have â instead of quotes?
Thank you, using LANG=C in bash fixed the quotes.

Repsonding here to answer so I can use formatting.
Excellent! I had no idea that libnet-config is a binary you can use on the command line for settings. So for other noobs,

```
$ libnet-config  --defines
-D_BSD_SOURCE -D__BSD_SOURCE -D__FAVOR_BSD -DHAVE_NET_ETHERNET_H
$ libnet-config --libs
-lnet
```

so you escape that so it runs as a command

```
$ gcc -Wall `libnet-config --defines` mitmc.c -o mitmc `libnet-config --libs` -lpcap
mitmc.c: In function 'main':
mitmc.c:232: warning: implicit declaration of function 'strlcat'
/tmp/ccSDMkcZ.o: In function `main':
mitmc.c:(.text+0x590): undefined reference to `strlcat'
mitmc.c:(.text+0x5c0): undefined reference to `strlcat'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Thanks for the help, that is the right answer. Now it appears the code was written for openbsd(see wikipedia Strlcpy). I guess i'll just replace the strlcat with strncpy and hope for the best. SUCCESS, it compiled! Oh FFS,

```
$ sudo ./mitmc
pcap_compile: syntax error
```

Ah that is just my usage.

**Thank you Vlad, thank you Jeremiah!**

Comment: The odd characters replacing quotes are from your locale setting; if you set the `LANG` environment variable to `C` when you compile, you will get normal quotes.

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify specific flags to your compiler/linker in order to use `libnet`. In your case, you see linker errors because it cannot find definitions for functions you are using in your program. Obviously, this is because you need to link with `libnet` and `libpcap`. To get it right, try something like:

```
gcc -Wall `libnet-config --defines` mitmc.c -o mitmc `libnet-config --libs` -lpcap
```

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, maybe there is a compiling for dummies FAQ? I thought the compiler new to get this because of the #include statements. Oh wow, for the other clueless, libnet-config actually produces output to use.    $ libnet-config  --defines
-D_BSD_SOURCE -D__BSD_SOURCE -D__FAVOR_BSD -DHAVE_NET_ETHERNET_H

Comment: The compiler knows the compile-time identifiers because you told the compiler to #include the source code in the .h file.  That doesn't tell anything to the linker.  You have to tell the linker separately.  The same thing happens in Visual Studio and other systems.